# Confusion on Python Memory Management

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, garbage-collection

**Background**: Sometimes, I repeatedly running the same cell on Jupyter Notebook for plotting, and it leads to kernel die. I suspect that it is related to memory issue. So I do the following test.

```
import gc
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def my_func():
    x = np.arange(0, 10)
    plt.plot(x, x)
    plt.show()

collected = gc.collect()
print(f"Garbage collector: collected {collected} objects")

print("Creating cycles...")
my_func()

collected = gc.collect()

print(f"Garbage collector: collected {collected} objects")
```

**Running on Jupyter Notebook**

```
Garbage collector: collected 51 objects
Creating cycles...
Garbage collector: collected 2250 objects
```

But when I run the notebook again (without restarting the kernel),

```
Garbage collector: collected 2290 objects
Creating cycles...
Garbage collector: collected 0 objects
```

**Running on Python Interpreter**

```
Garbage collector: collected 9 objects
Creating cycles...
Garbage collector: collected 0 objects
```

It looks like when I run the script on Python Interpreter, the figure object is automatically *freed* after it leaves `my_func`. But that's not the case for Jupyter Notebook. Could anyone explain the difference? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

jupyter notebook it is using  [IPython Kernel](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/overview.html) and after a run of your cell all the variables build at the cell run-time are kept in memory, this the point of using jupyter as an  interactive interpreter, if you want to free the memory for a jupyter notebook you can restart the kernel

---

I've been testing with your example on jupyter notebook, running the same cell again and again and I did not see your described behaviour after each rerun of the same cell:

```
Garbage collector: collected 2252 objects
```